# visual basic web browser links - perform action in program when clicked

Tags: html, vba, web

I have a web browser form inside my program, that displays a custom html page. When I click on the link, instead of going to another page, I would like it to do something in the program (tell the program to do something, and give it a variable or 2)

any suggestions? I was thinking maybe something javascript related, but I don't know much about how vb handles things like this

Comment: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/capture-webbrowser-navigation-events-not-question-but-solution-t3054763.html may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is not possible in vb.
but why do you need a webbrowser showing a custom site..
you could just copy the information from this site into your program, then replacing the links with actions in your program..

Comment: Because I want the interface to be customizable with CSS, but I want the program to do things that javascript can't =[

Answer (score 0):

Awesomium framework would be one way to do this. (http://www.awesomium.com/)
It lets you use HTML5 and CSS to make UI in .NET and in C++

I know, late answer.